# node JS: How to run a task for every 30 minutes , including now

Tags: node.js, cron

I'm running CronJob Every 30 mins.
But it is not running at the time of start.
How can i make it run at the time of start as well as every 30 min?

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
console.log('started ' + new Date());
    var job = new CronJob('0 */30 * * * *', function() {
            myJob()
        }, function () {

        },
        true, 
        'Indian/Mauritius'
    );
    job.start();

    function myJob()
    {
        console.log('in Job');
        console.log(new Date());
    }
```

Output

```
started Mon Sep 21 2015 18:44:29 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run `myJob()` and then start your cronjob.

or ...

you could change the way you use cron so that it runs at particular times, say now and every half hour like this:

```
var job = new CronJob('* 16,46 * * * *', // etc
```

Say the time is now 15:45, the above command will run in a minute (i.e. on the 16th and 46th minute of every hour). With a bit more code, you could generate the string "16,46" to be one minute from now and 30 minutes after that.